# D3 - Draw arrow on bar to reflect the data

Tags: d3.js

I have a plunker here  - https://plnkr.co/edit/qDi8bm3xh3hdaV059AXX?p=preview

Its a bar chart where the bars are drawn using a start and finish position.

The start position could be higher than the finish position so I have logic to still draw the bars in the correct position.

I'd like to draw an arrow on the bars to indicate if the start position is higher or lower than the finish position.

I have added a `data-arrow` to the bars (I've already used a class) which indicates if the arrow should be up or down.

```
.attr('data-arrow', (d, i) => {
    return d.start > d.finish ? 'down' : 'up'
})
```

Is it possible to draw some element on the bars to indicate the start position.

Is is possible to draw an arrow on each bar and then use the data attribute and css to rotate it the correct way

Comment: consider to set xScale to `rangeRound()`, for these small arrows you need two definitions to make it look good, so adding a rotation with CSS is not the ideal solution

Comment: How does setting the xScale to `rangeRound()` help here

Comment: @ttmt Doesn't my answer work?

Comment: it will result in a little crisper chart, why use rangeRound on Y but not on X, the solution is the other part of the comment

Comment: @rioV8, there are two questions here. I believe my answer addresses the first one. For the second one, your comment is the way to go. But I would recommend against adding arrows in this case as they only add clutter to this graph without conveying useful information. The axes do a much better job conveying direction information.

Comment: @jrook, it partly answers my question but I need it to show direction, something like - https://plnkr.co/edit/pSdqRqWWE1lSAm5oi465?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just draw the line in the other direction

```
  bar.enter()
    .append("line")
      .attr("x1", d => x(d.phase) + x.bandwidth()/2)
      .attr("y1", d => y(d.start) + ((d.start < d.finish) ? -10 : 10) )
      .attr("x2", d => x(d.phase) + x.bandwidth()/2)
      .attr("y2", d => y(d.finish) + ((d.start < d.finish) ? 15 : -15) )
      .attr('class', d => d.start > d.finish ? 'arrow-down' : 'arrow-up' )
      .attr("stroke","red")
      .attr("stroke-width",2)
      .attr("marker-end","url(#arrow)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quik solution: enter `bars` again and append arrows (or other shapes) to the `start` point of the bars:

```
bar.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cy", d => y(d.start))
    .attr("cx", d => x(d.phase) + x.bandwidth()/2)
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", "blue")
```

[Updated plankr](https://plnkr.co/edit/AdldzPyDe9HAK6UUmwcb?p=preview)

In this solution, there is no need for additional data attributes although it doesn't harm either. If it is important to show direction, in addition to the start point, I would also consider [gradients](https://www.freshconsulting.com/d3-js-gradients-the-easy-way/) because they generally add less clutter to the graph.

Note that the direction is implicitly known because of the y-axis. Adding an arrow does not really give new information unless we have data regarding the rate of change from min to max.